# Catalina.sh not found, The file is absent or does not have execute permission

Tags: permissions

I tried to start tomcat 8 through the terminal, but I have an issue related to permissions.

It appears that catalina.sh was not found.

[image: Terminal snapshot]

I'm new in Ubuntu, please advise how to solve this.

Answer (score 13):

To see permissions do `ls -l`.

A file with execute permissions has `x` in the string at the front. Here's an executable script on my system:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zanna zanna   7827 Jun 12 07:15 x205ta-iso2zip.sh
```

Here's one that isn't executable:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zanna zanna  24284 Jun 12 07:15 x205ta-iso2usb.sh
```

If catalina.sh does not have execute permissions then change the permissions:

```
chmod +x catalina.sh
```

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

To complement,

**Make at least the files `catalina.sh`, `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh`** inside `bin` executable:

```shell
chmod +x catalina.sh startup.sh shutdown.sh
```

or

```shell
chmod +x bin/*.sh
```

If you are using the `startup.sh`, I may remind you that `catalina.sh` also needs to be executable.